# Welcome page for android application

Tags: android, eclipse, branding

I have created an android application which should run on my Android based phone. As soon as the application is installed on the phone it proceeds with the task it is designed for. I want that as application is installed it should first open a welcome page displaying information about the product and on clicking OK button it should proceed to it's task.

Comment: you mean display splash screen in your app?

Comment: you should check the tutorials out here, You can find tons of code for starters. Do it , If you are stuck you can find the reason here in some posts

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/splash-screen-demo-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to create a Splash Screen layout and associated activity. You have to use a Timer or Thread to handle it. First create a `splash.xml` file and also create an activity `SplashActivity.java`.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {  
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash.xml);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startHomeActivity(); // start home after 3 seconds
            }
        }, 3000); // three seconds wait, you can change it


       }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do not exactly need splash screen as splash screen is used for performing background activities. What I am looking for is , as soon as my application is installed it should open up with welcome page ,providing information about the application and a step by step instructions of using the entire product i.e I read one instruction, press the next button and it should take me to next page with second instruction and so on. And finally when i click the finish button it should start its' designated activity/task.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are very much new to android development, i suggest you to learn more on android from [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/index.html), you will get all api level explanation with examples. And here the [link](http://androidexample.com/Splash_screen_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=113&aaid=135) to know step by step implementation of creating splash screen in you android application. Keep leaning, try to search from website, you will get plenty of references. :)